# Redshift: How to see columns that are analyzed in a table?

Tags: amazon-redshift

Is there a way to see the "Analyzed" values in a Redshift table?  In Teradata, the help stats command gives you this.  I'm wondering if there is an equivalent in Redshift.  Can't find anything on that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, with some work.  First off, remember that Redshift stores data in 1MB blocks and these blocks are distributed across the cluster (slices). So the metadata that is created by ANALYZE gives information about these blocks and what they contain.

The table stv_blocklist contains this information about block contents.  It contains a number of pieces of information about the blocks but the pieces that will likely be of most interest are minvalue and maxvalue (along with table id, slice, and column so you know what part of the database any block is a part of).

Minvalue and maxvalue are BIGINTs so these values can make perfect sense if the data column they are for are also BIGINTs. However, if your column is text or a timestamp you will need to do some reverse engineering to understand the hash used to be able to store values for these column types as BIGINTs.  I've done it for just about all data types in the past and it isn't too hard to work out.  If memory serves there is some endian trick with the text values but again not too hard to work things out since you can see the input values and output values.  With this decoder ring you can make evaluations on effectiveness of sort keys in speeding up queries.

Comment: Bill, what I'm really after is the something that'll show the columns/column combinations in a table that have stats on them already.  Will the stv_blocklist give me that?  I don't have access right now but can request if this gives me what I'm looking for.

Comment: I also don't have a cluster available ATM but if memory serves, yes, stv_blocklist gives this information.  My recollection is that if a block doesn't have valid stats then the minvalue will be the max bigint and the maxvalue will be the min bigint (no possibility of a metadata match).  Remember that a column can be partially analyzed since each column is made up of multiple blocks and they can have different stats validity based on table history.